# How to measure strike plate position?

Tags: archery, arrows

[Stu Miller's Dynamic Spine Calculator](http://heilakka.com/stumiller/) asks the user for the "strike plate position". How do I measure and add it correctly to the calculator?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to measure the strike plate position for the purposes of this calculation is given in the [instructions for the calculator](http://heilakka.com/stumiller/Dynamic%20Spine%20Calculator%20Instructions%207-18-10.pdf): [image]

Answer (score 4):

ShemSeger has a great explanation.

If we zoom into the graphic you can see where the measurement is made:

[image]

From blue line to blue line.